# Unique migration safe user id in firebase auth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase auth in my android app. What should be my **unique user id** in case of **google and facebook login** which I can associate with a user so that if in future we migrates our auth process to our own servers, we will be able to identify users ?

I know I'm currently getting a **unique uid** and an **idp token** but I'm not sure they are going to be same after migration.

Comment: If you migrate the authentication process to your own server, aren't the user IDs there under your own control?

Comment: user ids will be under my control but, how I will identify existing users, for ex:-currently for a user logging in via facebook, firebase gives me an id xyz(to identify user) but after migration if the same user logs in via facebook(direct api of facebook) , i don't think i will still be getting same id xyz, it may be different bec i will be getting it directly via facebook not via firebase....same is the issue with twitter and google login... I can't rely on email or phone bec they aren't mandatory and keeps on changing..

Comment: Hmmm... I can't find anywhere we expose. The approaches I can think of are matching up on some known value, such as email address or phone number, or implementing your own authentication as a custom provider for Firebase, so that you can link the accounts.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen as of now, apart from 'password' and 'mobile' login, I'm going to use 'login via google' bec it is super easy to use on android...i just want to ask you that, can I rely on google that they will continue to provide 'login via google' in firebase in an unlimited and free manner.... or in future if they will scrap firebase they will provide me same uid via another api(other than firebase if any)...??

Comment: Firebase is doing well and Google is investing heavily in it. We've never considered charging for sign-in with social providers, nor limiting it in any other fashion (beyond rate limits to counter abuse). That said: there are never any guarantees in business.